# how to resolve locale based messages with nodejs and intl-messageformat

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to add localisation to a nodejs app. I decided to try the intl-messageformat library because it seems a popular choice on npm and it's built by yahoo.

At least for me, it's a little unclear how the locale resolution works.

My background is java where there's a hierarchy of files, where if _en_AU exists, it take the message by code from a properties bundle. Otherwise if it doesn't exist, but en exists, it falls back to the same code message in the en bundle.

Reading the docs of the node library it appears to only support the hierarchical locales for it's internal resolution, presumably for genders and numbers etc. But not resolving the actual message.

The example on their site seems to indicate that the library doesn't support resolving hierarchical messages:  https://github.com/yahoo/intl-messageformat#common-usage-example  -

`var enNumPhotos = new IntlMessageFormat(MESSAGES['en-US'].NUM_PHOTOS, 'en-US');`

So 2 questions:

1. Am I correct in my understanding that the messages can't be resolved from a locale hierarchy using this package?
2. Is there an alternate library that will enable hierarchical locale message resolution?

Comment: If you want to solve this issue still, I want to know something about the issue. What did you mean by using "hierarchical"?  Did you want to specify that if the programmer defines the locales as `['en', 'de', 'es']`, then the `node.js` tries `en` when determining the user locale first, if the client user doesn't use `en` in browser the `node.js` tries `de`?

Comment: We made simple library for node which resolve your problem - https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-intl